# How do I send a list of objects through MessagingCenter in C#?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, messagingcenter

I am trying to send list of `BarData` objects to my `FavoritesPage.xaml.cs` through MessagingCenter. I have tried

`MessagingCenter.Send<BarData>(_favoriteBarsList, "FaveBars");`

and it gives me an error, telling me I can't convert the sender from a list to an object. I then tried to use

`MessagingCenter.Send<List<BarData>>(_favoriteBarsList, "FaveBars");`

and visual studio screams at me LOL!
I tried search online how to send a list of objects through MessagingCenter but I can't find anything. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MessagingCenter.Send Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.messagingcenter.send?view=xamarin-forms)

> Sends a named message with the specified arguments
>
> **Parameters**
>
> - sender `TSender`
>
>   - The instance that is sending the message. Typically, this is specified with the this keyword used within the sending object.
> - message `String`
>
>   - The message that will be sent to objects that are listening for the message from instances of type TSender.
> - args `TArgs`
>
>   - The arguments that will be passed to the listener's callback.

**Example**

```
MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage,List<BarData>>(
    this, // the context you are on 
    "FaveBars", // the named message
    _favoriteBarsList); // the argument
```

Where `MainPage` is the type of `this`, and `List<BarData>` is the argument type

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Would I still put ```MainPage``` even though I don't want the list of objects to be sent to the MainPage?

Comment: @MirandaHall Its not sending to the main page, its the page or context your are on, so replace MainPage, with where ever you are

Comment: How would you set up the Subscribe feature?